# Calling non static array from static method

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: how to call non static method from main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379915/java-how-to-call-non-static-method-from-main-method)

I am finding this a bit hard to implement.

I have a `String[]` called `name` which is declared `globally`.

```
String[]name;
```

Now i want to access this variable from the `main()` method. The main method is `static` therefore how could i access it.

I tried `Animal.name` but it didn't work.

How can i do this?

Comment: you don't have anything declared `globally` because Java doesn't have `global` variables

Comment: show all your code please

Comment: Like @JarrodRoberson said, Java doesn't have `global` variables.  Definining a variable in a class makes it an [instance variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) which only has scope inside instances of the Animal object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `Animal` class to access `instance fields`: -

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
animal.name;  // Access array
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with two different ways, each requiring code modification:

First is to create an object of `Animal` type and accessing the `name` property.

Second is to make `name` as `static`.

like this: `static String[] name = new String[10];`