# Java static methods + classes

Tags: java, methods, static, program-entry-point, static-methods

First off I want to say that I'm very new to Java, coming from a C++ background. I can never get in contact with my teacher so I would like to try to post this question here that I have been wondering for a while (hopefully I can word it correctly):

How do I create methods without using `static` ? I know I probably need to make a class for it but how do I go about it? Just a class without variables and just functions? Do I make a second class that encompasses main other than the class named after the .java file? For instance:

```
package musiclibrary;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class implements a user to create a playlist from a selection of artists and songs
 * @author ahb5190
 */
public class MusicLibrary {
static String divider = "*****************************************************";
//Scanner class
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

/**
 * Welcome menu
 */
public static void welcomeMenu()
{
    System.out.println(divider);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Welcome to Art's personal music library!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Choose an option:");
    System.out.println("1) Create Playlist");
    System.out.println("2) Delete Playlist");
    System.out.println("3) Add Selection to Playlist");
    System.out.println("4) Remove Selection from Playlist");
    System.out.println("5) Quit");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Your choice?: ");
}

/**
 * 
 * @param min error check low bound
 * @param max error check high bound
 * @return 
 */
public static int getData(int min, int max)
{
   boolean goodInput = false;
    int choice = 1; //Will be overwritten
    while(!goodInput)
    {    
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if(choice < min || choice > max)
        {
            System.out.print(choice + " is not a valid choice. Please enter a number between " + min + " and " + max + ": ");
            goodInput = false;
        }
        else
        {
            goodInput = true;
        }
    }

    return choice;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Variables
    int getDataMin = 1;
    int getDataMax = 5;
    boolean quit = false;
    int userInput;

    do {
        welcomeMenu();
        userInput = getData(getDataMin, getDataMax);
        if (userInput == 1)
        {
            quit = false;
        }
        else  if (userInput == 2)
        {
            quit = false;
        }
        else  if (userInput == 3)
        {
            quit = false;
        }
        else if (userInput == 4)
        {
            quit = false;
        }
        else  if (userInput == 5)
        {
            quit = true;
        }
    } while(!quit);

}
```

}

is the very beginning of a java program that was assigned. If I remove `static` from  `public static void welcomeMenu()` it gives me `non-static method welcomeMenu() cannot be referenced from a static context` when I try to call `welcomeMenu();` in main.

Another block of code (not very neat, was part of a timed exam):

```
package lalala;

/**
 *
 * @author ahb5190
 */
public class Lalala {


    public class Movie
    {
        private String title;
        private String genre;
        private String director;
        private String star;

        public Movie (String t, String g, String d, String s)
        {
            title = t;
            genre = g;
            director = d;
            star = s;
        }
        public String gettitle()
        {
            return title;
        }
        public String getGenre()
        {
            return genre;
        }
        public String getDirector()
        {
            return director;
        }
        public String getStar()
        {
            return star;
        }
        public void setTitle(String x)
        {
            title = x;
        }
        public void setGenre(String x)
        {
            genre = x;
        }
        public void setDirector(String x)
        {
            director = x;
        }
        public void setsStar(String x)
        {
            star = x;
        }
        public boolean equals(Movie otherMovie)
        {
            if(otherMovie == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return title.equals(otherMovie.title) && genre.equals(otherMovie.genre) && director.equals(otherMovie.director) && star.equals(otherMovie.star);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return(title + " " + genre + " " + director + " " + star);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Movie a;
        a = new Movie("Star Trek into Darkness", "Sci-fi", "J.J. Abrams", "Chris Pine");  //error: non-static variables this cannot be referenced from a static context
        Movie b = new Movie("Star Trek", "Sci-Fi", "J.J. Abrams", "Chris Pine");  //error: non-static variables this cannot be referenced from a static context
        Movie c = new Movie("Independence Day", "Action", "Roland Emmerich", "Will Smith"); //error: non-static variables this cannot be referenced from a static context

        System.out.println("Movies");

        System.out.println("Title: " + a.title);
        System.out.println("Genre: " + a.genre);
        System.out.println("Director: " + a.director);
        System.out.println("Star: " + a.star);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Title: " + b.title);
        System.out.println("Genre: " + b.genre);
        System.out.println("Director: " + b.director);
        System.out.println("Star: " + b.star);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Title: " + c.title);
        System.out.println("Genre: " + c.genre);
        System.out.println("Director: " + c.director);
        System.out.println("Star: " + c.star);
        System.out.println();

        a.equals(b);

    }

}
```

gives me same static variable error as before, as commented on the code above. In that scenario, how I got it to 'work' was to remove `static` from `public static void main(String args[])`.

Really trying to learn the right way to Java, any help would be appreciated. Also I hope this meets MCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access non static members of a class you need an instance of that class.

So `new Movie("a", "b", "c", "d").getGenre()` is legal.

Removing static keyword from main is not legal since it is the entry point of your program and thus it is mandatory to exists.

**EDIT**: 
In the first source, the main() method does not create any instance of MusicLibrary, that's why you need to use static on all members.

Add `MusicLibrary lib = new MusicLibrary();` then call `lib.welcomeMenu();` and you can get rid of static keyword.

Comment: Still gives me the same error when I put static back in. I only took static out for the written exam so I could test for any syntax errors on the rest of the code, I understand static must be there :)

Comment: I've edited the answer to be more specific on your case.

Comment: Ahh!!! Thank you so much! I knew it was something small  :)  I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all non-static methods can be call only with instance of the class,

This [link](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-vs-non-static-methods/) might help, to understand it a bit.And this type of question is already been answered here: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379915/java-how-to-call-non-static-method-from-main-method)

Comment: And For the another part of question, place the class _Movie_ outside of the class _lalala_, its causing static member error because its in the same contex with _static void main()_