# Why we use new to call a method in this code?

Tags: java

Consider the following java code.

```
public class A {

  public static void main (String [] args){

    Temp p = new Temp();
    p.name = "Name";
    new A().changeValue(p);
    System.out.print(p.name);
  }

  public void changeValue(Temp t){
    t.name ="changeValue";
  }
}

class Temp{
  String name;
}
```

Well I got confused about this line : `new A().changeValue(p);` 
this is the first time for me to see like this line! is this anonymous object or?? also what is the output please! please explain with steps .

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: how to call non static method from main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379915/java-how-to-call-non-static-method-from-main-method)

Comment: You could run the code to find the output yourself? Or are you confused about the output you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new A().changeValue(p);
```

> is this anonymous object or??

Yes, you are creating a new instance of `A` without assigning it to a variable name.  Then you immediately call `changeValue()` on that object. Note that you can rewrite this as two lines that gives the same result:

```
A a = new A();
a.changeValue(p);
```

In fact, this is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent to

```
A temporary = new A();
temporary.changeValue(p);
```

Basically, since `changeValue` is not `static`, an instance of `A` is needed to invoke the method.

So the code is creating an instance and directly invoking a method on the object just created.