# implementation problem and code optimization

Tags: java, arrays, list, optimization

I'm studying CS and am still a Java / programming noob, we've got following code in class and have to explain the problems with the following method and are supposed to optimize it:

```java
public static void printData(int[] list) {
   int i = 0;
   do {
       System.out.println(list[i++]);
   } while (i < list.length);
}
```

So, my first thought is that it's of course possible to use a do-while loop, but that I would have used a for loop such as:

```java
public static void pd(int[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        System.out.println(list[i]);
}
```

for optimization.

Now, the other method is also possible tho and I cannot figure out the problem with it, maybe that it's not too compatible because of the `static` declaration, but I'm starting to wrap my head around how to deal with calling `non-static`methods from main, if you have any other advice, I've got open ears.

Comment: The two will be as fast because such transformation is trivial to do for the JVM. Such micro optimization is pointless nowodays. Not to mention the IOs operations are far more costly that what you could gain if the JVM what not optimizing your code. You should focus first on the *algorithm*.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hints to work on:

1. What happens in the method provided "printData" if the length of the input array is 0?
2. What if the list you're getting as input is null?

About the thing with `non-static` methods, they can only be called upon the instance on the class and not independently.
You can find more in this [other question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379915/java-how-to-call-non-static-method-from-main-method)

Comment: It's not homework, just refreshing old material for a new class.

Anyway, I think I see: ```printData``` will only work *while* i<list.length, ```pd```will run once before stopping and not throw an outofbounds exception

How to input null into the array?

thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm sorry, you mentioned a class and made an assumption. Anyway, about the Null stuff. You are taking an input without sanitizing it. It means that, were the list to be null, list.length would throw a NullPointerException. To prevent it you might just add a if (list == null) and if true you quit the method. As a rule of thumb you should always sanitize input so you don't incur in exceptions like NullPointers.

Comment: ah, I see

I also think I made a mistake, the for-loop with evaluate the condition before it runs, so it just doesn't run and throw the exception, right? 
Why exactly does ```printData```still throw an exception, do while-loops not also evaluate before running?  I mean, if ```i !< list.length``` because ```i=0``` and ```list.length```is also zero, why is it still executed?

Comment: Not sure, are you talking about the NullPointer or regarding the zero-length array? Not sure I understand the question